# bash numeric array extract number and add to the var

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, scripting

Have to ask here, cause can't find any answer on the web...

I have indexed bash array `{$x[$i]}` and need to do extract a number and add it to `$sum`, but it doesn't work.
Wrong code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a x 

x[0]=1
x[1]=2
x[2]=3
x[3]=4
x[4]=5
```

## Following won't work

```
$SUM=$((SUM+{$x[0]))
$SUM=$((SUM+{$x[1])) 
$SUM=$((SUM+{$x[2]))

echo $SUM
```

Please, help!

Comment: Don't user uppercase variable names in your script. If you're not careful, you'll end up overwriting a shell internal variable, e.g. `$HOME` or `$PATH` at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra start brace and $ for accessing array element, remove that. So change it from:

```
SUM=$((SUM+{$x[0]))
```

To

```
SUM=$((SUM+x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. When you assign a variable, you don't put `$` before the variable being assigned. Second, you're missing the closing `}` around your array references. Third, the `{` comes *after* the `$`. It should be:

```
SUM=$((SUM+${x[0]}))
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove the `${}` entirely within an arithmetic context.

Comment: And you can use `+=` inside the arithemic context:   `((sum+=x[0]))`